# Nextcord: I want to mention the sender of the slash command I made. How would I go about that?

Tags: discord, bots, nextcord

I'm trying to make this command notify my admins of a bot test and need it to mention the user who called the command. How would I go about that? I don't fully understand how to get that information with slash commands.

```py
@client.slash_command(name= "test", description="(For Deputies or Leader only) Checks the operational state of the client.", guild_ids=[806043206030589952])
@has_any_role(leader_id, deputy_id)
async def test(interaction:Interaction):
  bot_log = channel_up(940125176723554394)
  await bot_log.send(f'<@&806045254834847776>,{} has started diagnostics for the bot. Please ignore any possible disturbances for the next minute or so.')
```

Thanks in advance for the advice, it's the first discord bot I've ever created.

EDIT:
In documentation, I found the solution. I have to use `interaction.user.mention` to get it to mention the user who sent the command. Or at least in theory, I'm dealing with a different issue now. Hopefully this helps people who also were as confused as me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `interaction.user.name` function with an `@` at the beginning.

The code should look something like this:

```
await interaction.response.send_message("@"+str(interaction.user.name))
```